# iOS 13 Application window is wrongly rotated on iPhone if app is started with iPhone in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios13, screen-orientation

I'm in the process of upgrading a 10 years old iOS application (Objective-C) for iOS 13 (Xcode 11.4) and noticed the following strange issue: When the app is launched while the iPhone (Simulator, 13.4) is in landscape orientation, the app's window has the correct dimensions, but is strangely rotated 90 degrees to the right. This does not happen on iPad (Simulator, 13.4) or iPhone Simulator 12.x where the app launches correctly.
Attached is a screenshot to better illustrate the issue.
The app is using XIBs and programmatically created views, no storyboards.
The initial view is created in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the usual way:

```
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The `tabBarController` is loaded from a XIB.

The Launch Screen (which is the only storyboard in the app) is shown correctly.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of app showing strange rotation bug when launched in landscape orientation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that removing the line

```
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` did the trick. Apparently this line was needed once, but causes havoc now.

Removing the line also fixed the `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: ...>` message I was seeing in the log output.

See also [this answer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/127714#401180) in the Apple Developer Forums which brought me on the right track.